# Runtime error ( IllegalArgumentException) when using SimpleCursorAdapter - column '_id' does not exist

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I try to get some db values and display them in a listview.

Here is my code:

```
public class SearchCustomer extends Activity{    

private DBCreater dbHelper;

private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.search_customer);

    dbHelper = new DBCreater(this);
    dbHelper.open();

    displayListView();
}

private void displayListView(){

    Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchallcustomerdata();
    String[] columns = new String[] {
        DBCreater.Key_customer_Name,
        DBCreater.Key_customer_Shop,
        DBCreater.Key_customer_Location,
        DBCreater.Key_customer_Phon,
        DBCreater.Key_customer_Email,
        DBCreater.Key_customer_Address
    };

    int[] to = new int[]{
            R.id.tv_I_name_demo,
            R.id.tv_I_shop_demo,
            R.id.tv_I_location_demo,
            R.id.tv_I_phone_demo,
            R.id.tv_I_email_demo,
            R.id.tv_I_address_demo
    };

    final ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_I_listofcustomer_searchCustomer);
     dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.demosearch, cursor, columns, to,0);
    listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> lidstView, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Cursor cursor =(Cursor)listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            //Toast.makeText(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(""), text, duration)
            String name=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("customer_name"));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    EditText myFilter = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_I_filter_searchCustomer);
    myFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dataAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    dataAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {

        @Override
        public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return dbHelper.fetchcustomerbyname(constraint.toString());
        }
    });
}


}
```

I get RuntimeException of `IllegalArgumentException`

This is the error:

> 03-11 20:11:24.650: E/AndroidRuntime(887): java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.NIRR.redistributionsystem/com.NIRR.redistributionsystem.SearchCustomer}:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist

This is my db query:

```
public Cursor fetchallcustomerdata() {
    /*Cursor mCursor=ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE_CUSTOMER,new String[]{
            Key_customer_Name,Key_customer_Shop,Key_customer_Location,Key_customer_Phon,
            Key_customer_Email,Key_customer_Address},null,null,null,null,null,null);*/
     String selectQuery = "select  customer_name,customer_shop,customer_location,customer_phon,customer_email,customer_address from Customer" ;

        SQLiteDatabase db = ourHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if(mCursor != null){
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```

the sql query that i use is give me the correct when it run on SQLite db browser.
I don't know what is the `column '_id'` that was say as "Does not exit"
The error come form this line

```
dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.demosearch, cursor, columns, to,0);
```

please help me
thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) for `CursorAdapter`, of which `SimpleCursorAdapter` is a subclass :

> The Cursor must include a column named "_id" or this class will not work.

If your table already has a column named "_id", then just include this in the query's projection (the requested columns).

```
String selectQuery = "select _id, customer_name, ... from Customer";
```

If your table doesn't have an "_id" column, you can instead alias the "rowid" that all SQLite tables have by default (excepting those explicitly created without one).

```
String selectQuery = "select rowid as _id, customer_name, ... from Customer";
```

The same can be done even if you're not using raw SQL. For example, in a `query()` call:

```
mCursor = db.query("Customer", new String[] {"rowid as _id", "customer_name", ...}, ...);
```

You can, of course, alias another column you might already have, if it's equivalent to an "_id". Do note, though, that you must use the alias name - i.e., "_id" - with the `Cursor`, should you be manually retrieving values from it.